# useEffect is returning undefined even though "then" is returning a value response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, use-effect

I can't seem to figure out why useEffect is doing this... Wait() is a sleep async function, getData() is an Axios request.

```
        return wait().then(getData().then((resp) => {
            console.log(resp)
        }))
```

This code logs a valid value for the resp variable but it returns undefined in the return statement. What is going on and how do I get it to return the resp variable instead?

EDIT***

```
const wait = React.useCallback( async() => {
    if (loading === false) {
        await sleep(4000);
    } else if (loading === true){
        await sleep(0);
    } else {
        await sleep(2000);
    }
}, [loading])

const getData = React.useCallback(() => {
    const value = Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/get-value",
    {user: userProp}).then((response) => {
        const recievedData = response.data;
        const dataValue = recievedData.map((val) => {
            return [val.value]
        })
            if (loading === true){
                setLoading(false);
            }
        return parseInt(dataValue);
    }).then((resp) => {
        setMoisture(resp) // if I turn this off still no go.
        return resp
    })
    return value
}, [userProp, loading])

const Data = React.useCallback(() => {
    try {
        return wait().then(getData)
    } catch (error) {
        setError(true);
        return error;
        }   
}, [wait, getData])

React.useEffect(() => {
    let isEffect = false
    if (props.location.state !== undefined) {
        Data().then((firstResponse) => {
            if (!isEffect){
                setMoisture(firstResponse)
            }
        })
    }
    return () => {
        isEffect = true;
    }
}, [props.location.state, Data, moisture]);
```

Comment: Your chaining isn't exact correct and you also need to return the value at the end. Try something like this: `return wait().then(getData).then(resp => resp)` though if you aren't doing anything in the final `.then` beside returning the value, then it isn't actually required and you can omit it

Comment: Thanks you! This solved my undefined issue but my state is no longer updating.

Comment: Ok but how are you trying to update the state? Add all relevant code

Comment: Ok I added more code. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the callback provided to the useEffect must return either a function or undefined (if a function is provided, this is considered a clean-up function. the clean-up function is used to detach event listeners, cancel any on-going request, and prevent any update if the component gets unmounted)

In order to access the response resulted from your http request, you should store it in a piece of state (you can use useState or useReducer)

```
const [rest, setResp] = React.useState();

React.useEffect(() => {
 wait().then(_ => getData()).then(setResp);
}, [YOUR_DEPENDENCIES]);

// update jsx based on rest
```

based on the updates in your question, what you need is polling

Please review the example below (keep in mind that is code to illustrate the possible solution)

```js
function usePolling(fetcher, interval) {
  const [payload, setPayload] = React.useState(null);
  
  React.useEffect(function () {
    // you must implement the error handling
    fetcher()
      .then(function (resp) {
        setPayload(resp)
      })
    
  }, [fetcher]);
  
  React.useEffect(function () {
    let timeoutId;
    
    function poll() {
      timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        // you must implement the error handling
        fetcher()
          .then(function (resp) {
            setPayload(resp)
            poll();
          })
      }, interval);
    }
    poll()
    
    return function () {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }
  }, [fetcher, interval]);
  
  return payload;
}


function App() {
  const payload = usePolling(function () {
    return Promise.resolve(Date.now())
  }, 3000);
  
 
  return (
    <div>polling payload: {payload}</div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I do this, it stops updating the state. Any idea why? To clarify I am using axios to get data from mysql which has new data coming to it every 10 seconds.

Comment: I do not know why you are using useCallback so much (looks like you are optimizing way too early)

Comment: It was because I kept getting warnings telling me to use it. That is literally the only reason. lol

Comment: the warnings were probably for the useEffect and not the useCallback (you should check it out closely). I have updated my answer to illustrate what might be a possible solution to your problem

Comment: usePolling will call the fetcher function based on the given interval value

Comment: Thank. I will give this a go and get back!

Comment: How would I call my getData() function when using this function   const payload = usePolling(function () {
    return Promise.resolve(Date.now())
  }, 3000);

Comment: const payload = usePolling(function () {
        return Promise.resolve(getData())
      }, 3000);

Comment: It is working now. Thank you so much. This took my entire day today.

Comment: There is one issue with this. Inside the function poll() it calls poll() again in the "then" which allows this to update state every n seconds. However, I have a redirect on my front end and it is causing a memory leak. The front end redirects to the correct page but the console is still showing this function running. How do I kill this on redirect?